# ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file 'C:\Outfile.txt' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)

Tags: mysql, permissions

All of a sudden, I cannot write to a file from MySQL.  I am using Windows 10 and MySQL version 5.7.18-log.  My query runs fine but when I add `INTO OUTFILE 'C:/Outfile.txt'`
it returns `ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file 'C:\Outfile.txt' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)`

I have edited the my.ini file at C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\.  It originally had `secure-file-priv= ""` which, as I understand it, should mean I have permission to write anywhere.  I changed my.ini to `secure-file-priv= "C:\"` but I still get the same error.

Is there somewhere else that I can change permissions or something that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to give permission to file from file properties and give all permission to file

Comment: Thank you Usman! That took care of it.  I might point out that it took a reboot as well.